# Adding Home widget in Android Using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Does Flutter support adding a home widget in Android?

I have searched a package for that, but couldn't find one.

The picture below shows what I need:

[image]

Comment: No, it doesnt you can find some packages that try to do it but they are incomplete and may not support your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget) to get further knowledge about this.

`HomeWidget` is a Plugin to make it easier to create HomeScreen Widgets on `Android` and `iOS`. `HomeWidget` does not allow writing Widgets with `Flutter` itself. It still requires writing the Widgets with native code. However, it provides an unified Interface for sending data, retrieving data and updating the Widgets.